# Showing categories related to main category only in product category filter instead of showing all in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce i am using  product category filter. I have this hierarchy

```
> Main category1-level1
>      subcategory1-level2
>               subcategory-level3
>      subcategory1-level2
>               subcategory1-level3
>               subcategory2-level3
```

what i wanted is when a subcategory is selected the product filter has to display parent categories related to that category instead of displaying all product categories. for example if i take subcategory2-level3 in that page i want to show only categories under that main category. Now it is showing all product categories in the website. I am not attaching any tried code, since i have no idea of it. Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was i mised this code in functions.php.

get_theme_support('woocommerce');

it solved the issue.